# how to specify default values for model with user FK in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have looked at the questions for extending user fields in django and thought of using the FK to user method:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    contact_means = models.IntegerField()
    parent_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
```

I have a question here. With this method (compared to user inheritance), in the admin site, after i registered Parent, how do I specify default values for the USER attributes like 'is_active' and or hide USER fields in the edit page? Can I even do that in Parent's ModelAdmin class ?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean by specifying default attributes for user after registering Parent?

Are you creating the user object from your Parent object? I could help better if I understood the flow between your User object creation and Parent object creation.

**To hide your user field:** specify the `fields` attribute. This assumes that user has already been set.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('contact_means',)
```